# Show unqualified field names in ArcGIS Server map service

Tags: arcgis-server, fields-attributes, esri-geodatabase, arcgis-10.6, map-service

We have two tables:

1. `[Server1].[Instance1].[Database1].[dbo].[Districts]` -- a versioned polygon feature class with only two fields: a shape and a foreign key
2. `[Server1].[Instance2].[Database2].[dbo].[vwDistricts]` -- a rather straightforward view on a non-spatial table containing the other end of the foreign key and useful information about the districts.

I have created a map service--on a standalone ArcGIS Server instance running v 10.6.1--that contains a join between these two tables. The view is fed by a separate table in `[Database2]` that holds the authoritative values for these data so it is necessary to maintain this join to keep the data fresh.  The problem is that the resulting map service publishes fully qualified field names (`Database1.dbo.Districts.DistrictNumber` and `Database2.dbo.vwDistricts.Name`), and I'd like very much to avoid revealing specific database names & table names to the world.

I've tried publishing from ArcMap and from ArcGIS Pro (v 2.6.1).  In ArcGIS Pro, I unchecked the [Join Tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/add-join.htm)'s "[Maintain Fully Qualified Field Names](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/environment-settings/qualified-field-names.htm)" setting; but that gives me no love, not even [intermittently](https://community.esri.com/thread/233111-fully-qualified-field-names). Is there a reliable way (either in ArcMap or Pro or elsewise) to get that map service published with unqualified names?

Comment: Have you already tried using the SQL `AS` statement to create an alias for your field name? It would help if you could post some of the SQL query your service is using as its data source.

Comment: @DanC I assume you mean in vwDistricts. Yeah I thought of that and tried it (to no avail) while writing this question.

Comment: I have an AGS service running with a layer in it that is pulling data from a database view with joins to tables in a few different databases, and I can change the field names in the layer's attribute table to whatever I want using `AS` in the view. This is on MS SQL Server 2016, AGS 10.4.1, MXD published from ArcMap 10.7.1. The difference would appear to be that my tables are all in the **same** SQL Server instance and yours are not. So maybe you can test using a modified query which draws all its data from one instance.

Comment: I considered that (which is why I noted that in the question) but was just a little too lazy to test it without being prodded.  Alas, I've now tested it (only in Pro for the moment because something about our domain chokes when I switch between Pro & ArcMap when dealing with AGS and now I can't publish from ArcMap) but still no love.  Thank you @Dan.

Comment: Now also tried using ArcMap 10.6.1.  Trying 10.8.1 next . . .